# iPhone 6, 5, 4: Firefox/Safari/Chrome randomly scrolling down page

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, browser, scroll

We're experiencing a very odd issue when testing on our development environment on the iPhone 6, 5 and 4: regardless of which browser we use, as we're navigating around the site, the page randomly scrolls down the page - the amount it scrolls varies too.

We're proxying our wifi connection so that we can access our local machines to test with.

We have a branch of our site which is the exact code and everything that is deployed to our live site. When browsing the live site no auto-scrolling happens at all. When accessing our 'test' live environment, the same issue happens.

The only difference here is having a proxied wifi connection and where the website we're accessing lives - we are literally comparing the two exact sites.

The fact that it happens across 3 browsers makes me think it's more of a phone related issue as opposed to some browser-specific problem (or any coding issues)

When testing with Samsung S6 or any other phone (haven't tried on another iPhone version) then the problem does not happen.

I know this is a really vague question - just typing it out is baffling me as I can't think what could possibly cause this! Any insight is greatly appreciated.

I initially thought this was an iPhone 6 problem but further testing using colleague's iPhone 5 and 4 has revealed the exact same issue. This is extremely baffling!

Thanks.

Comment: Follow-up: I've basically stripped back all of our JavaScript to one external library (mega menu) and the issue still exists -- this is driving me nuts, and is preventing a publish. I'm pretty sure the issue is tied down to our environment and won't actually be a problem once released live

Comment: Okay it's definitely related to the environment -- we FTP'd our live site (which doesn't have the issue) over to our internal server and set up a new site in IIS. When accessing this with the iPhone 4, 5 or 6 the scrolling problem starts to happen straight away. So something proxying our WiFi connection causes it! Crazy.